# Make function return the result of a promise inside of it

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have a function:

```
checkIfReadyToUse(){
 return this.af.object("/cardReady").query.once("value").then(data => data.val());
  }
```

That i want to use to get the value of cardReady. The problem is when i use that function, it returns like this and not true or false:

```
ZoneAwarePromise {_
_zone_symbol__state: null, 
_zone_symbol__value:
```

How can i make that it returns the value of cardReady and not this zone symbol?

Comment: May you share how you use `checkIfReadyToUse`?

Comment: `.then(data => return data.val());`

Comment: @PatricNox thats the same thing that he has, just a more verbose way of writing it

Comment: this.loyaltyCardReady = this.promotionService.checkIfReadyToUse(); like this

Comment: yea, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what `data.val()` returns, my assumption is that you are not doing a `.then()` or `await` on the execution of `checkIfReadyToUse`, as it will return a promise also.

```
const result = await checkIfReadyToUse()
console.log(result)
```

or

```
checkIfReadyToUse().then((result) => console.log(result))
```

depending if you use the `.then()` or `async/await` syntax

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get the resolved value of a promise is to `await` it inside an `async` function.

```js
const resolveTrue = () => Promise.resolve(true)
const resolveFalse = () => Promise.resolve(false)

;(async () => {
    if (await resolveTrue()) console.log('this logs')
    
    if (await resolveFalse()) console.log('this doesn’t')
    
    if (resolveFalse()) {
        console.log('this logs, because we forgot to await (an un-awaited Promise is truthy)')
    }
})()
```

You can alternatively call `.then` on the returned promise:

```js
functionReturningPromise().then(result => { /* do stuff with result */ })
```

However, `async/await` is typically better for two reasons:

1. It tends to be more readable (`.then` chains can become the new version of "callback hell" if you have too many of them).
2. [You'll get better stack traces](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-stack-traces) (if your transpilation target supports it).

---

Aside: I'm not sure if Angular's `ZoneAwarePromise` is built on top of native promises or not, but note that `async/await` can be used *even on non-native Promises*, as long as they implement the [`then`able protocol](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/thenable). For example:

```js
const FakePromise = (val) => {
    return { then: cb => setTimeout(() => cb(val), 1000) }
}

;(async () => {
    const result = await FakePromise('val')

    console.log(result) // this works! 
})()
```

Comment: Why's that the best way?

Comment: I think there is no best or worse. But the syntactic sugar async/await is there for a reason: There is no callback hell and there is no "never ending" promise-chain. In short: Its easier to read.

Comment: @PatricNox Firstly, it tends to be more readable (`.then` chains can become the new version of "callback hell" if you have too many of them). But also, [because you'll get better stack traces](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-stack-traces) (if your transpilation target supports it).